# How to prevent my submitHandler() from executing when HTML builtin form validation fails?

Tags: html, forms, validation

Here's [what I'm working on.](https://repl.it/@moonshiner/forms-2#index.html)
I followed this [MDN HTML5 Built-in form validation quide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation). The only criteria for my form is that all 3 questions must be answered. I'm at the point that when the user clicks the Submit button, all questions that have not been answered are highlighted and there's a small popup. I did not write any Javascript for this, just a bit of CSS that was in the guide:

```
<style>
        input:invalid,
        select:invalid {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }

        input:valid,
        select:valid {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }

        input:invalid:required,
        select:invalid:required {
            border: 1px dashed orange
        }
    </style>
```

My Submit button has `onclick="submitHandler()"` and all that function does is console.log() the values of the user inputs:

```
  <script>
    function submitHandler(){
      const inp = document.getElementById('age').value
      const dropdowns = document.getElementsByTagName('select')
      console.log(inp, dropdowns[0].value, dropdowns[1].value)
      console.log("Submit button clicked.")
    }
  </script>
```

The **problem** is that the code inside submitHandler() executes whenever the Submit button is clicked, however, I only want this to happen when **the form is valid**.

If there is built-in form validation, I'm hoping there is a built-in flag such as formIsInvalid or similar that I can use in my submitHandler(). Is there such a thing? (I'm trying to use built-in/vanilla features because my form is simple.)

Thanks!

Comment: so why are you not listening to the form submission?

Comment: Because I'm not submitting any forms just yet. I'm collecting the data and will create 1 POST request at the very end. There are many forms after this first form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Use the submit event instead of click event

If you have validation (selects MUST have empty option and required to be validated) you will not see the console.logs until the form is valid

```js
document.getElementById("formID").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // so you can see the values
  const inp = document.getElementById('age').value;
  const dropdowns = [...document.querySelectorAll('select')].map(sel => sel.value)
  console.log(inp, dropdowns);
  console.log("Submit button clicked.");

});
```

```html
<form id="formID">
  <input type="number" id="age" required />

  <select required>
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
  </select>

  <select required>
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```